# Rspec controller testing with Devise cannot test redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I am simply trying to test that a `:user` that is not signed in, will be redirected to the `new_user_session_path` when they try to access something they cannot.

When I call:

```
describe "GET new" do 
    it 'expects redirect unless admin' do
        get :new
        expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
    end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
1) MealsController GET new expects redirect unless admin
     Failure/Error: redirect_to new_user_session_path, alert: "You must be signed in to access this page."

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `new_user_session_path' for #<MealsController:0x007fa066d5d230>
       Did you mean?  new_user_invitation_path
```

**Why is this happening?**

Edit:  Here are my user routes:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 sessions#new
              user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 sessions#create
      destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                sessions#destroy
         new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                            devise/passwords#new
        edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                           devise/passwords#edit
             user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                           PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                           POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#create
    accept_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/accept(.:format)                                                       devise/invitations#edit
    remove_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/remove(.:format)                                                       devise/invitations#destroy
       new_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/new(.:format)                                                          devise/invitations#new
           user_invitation PATCH  /users/invitation(.:format)                                                              devise/invitations#update
                           PUT    /users/invitation(.:format)                                                              devise/invitations#update
                           POST   /users/invitation(.:format)                                                              devise/invitations#create
    edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                                    devise/registrations#edit
         user_registration PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of `$ rails routes | grep user`

Comment: I've added them.

Comment: Notice that the controller/action to `new_user_session_path` is `sessions#new` instead of `devise/sessions#new`. Have you ceated a custom `sessions` controller?

Comment: I did create a custom sessions controller.  How do I get past this in the test?